# adding keys to info.plist in Xcode

Tags: react-native

And yet, another glaring hole in my knowledge about developing things pops up..

But, after some internetz, I find that in order to make geolocation work in react native apps, I need to:

> You need to include the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist to enable geolocation when using the app.

that makes sense, this is the bit that makes the native tools talk to the js framework (I think).. but how do I add a value to that plist file? What does that key look like?

Comment: Did you scaffold your application with `create-react-native-app`?

Comment: thanks Dan, i didn't scaffold the app with the react native tools... hence the manual steps required.. A-J-A nailed it below however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pressing on the plus button marked in red circle search for
 => Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description ... Then you will have to add a description right beside it

[image: press on the add button and]

This should be your result 
PS make sure you open info.plist as property list to implement the way i'm showing.

[image]

Hope this helps !